# reload data in TabItem from another window when changing tab on tabcontrol WPF

Tags: wpf

I am sure that I have searched alot and tried many ways to solve it. but I could not do it.

I have a user control like this:

```
public partial class Categories : UserControl
{
    public Categories()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void GetCats()
    {
        string sqlcmdString = "select * from categories";
        string connString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-L6OBVA4\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=QLDB;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgv_categories.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
    }
}
```

and the main window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>  {
            new TabItem() { Content = new Import(), Header = "Import from Excel files"},
            new TabItem() { Content = new Categories(), Header = "Categories" },
            new TabItem() { Content = new Products(), Header = "Products"}
        };

        tabControl.ItemsSource = tabs;
    }


    private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource == this.tabControl)
        {
            if (this.tabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
               // personally, i need to do something here to call GetCats() method to reload all all categories from database to datagridview

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call GetCats() method in User control from main Window? or other words, how to update TabItem[1], that means: tab of Categories. to get new data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the `Content` property of the currently selected `TabItem`:

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource == this.tabControl)
    {
        if (this.tabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            TabItem ti = tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
            Categories c = ti.Content as Categories;
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.GetCats();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aw! it works fine. thank you very much. you made my day.